# Use of unresolved identifier 'json' in swift4

Tags: json, swift, swift4

I have error `Use of unresolved identifier 'json'`. Just now I'm using swift4. 
I just want to get json data and return 3 type of msg based on return parameter.

Fast msg(このクーポンは取得済です) means "it's already saved".

Second msg(マイクーポンに追加されました) means "it's saved now".

Third msg(マイクーポンに追加できませんでした) means "app cannot save that". > This is because there is lacking registered user parameter.

How can I solve `Use of unresolved identifier 'json'` problem in swift4 ??

```
@objc func saveCouponToMyCoupon() {

    let params = [
        "merchant_id" : ApiService.sharedInstance.merchant_id,
        "coupon_id" : self.coupon?.coupon_id
        ] as! [String : String]

    Alamofire.request(APIURL.k_Coupon_Publish, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding(destination: .httpBody), headers: ApiService.sharedInstance.header)
        .validate(statusCode: 200..<500)
        .responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let data):
                print(response)
                print(response.result)

                if json["returnCode"] == "E70" {
                    ErrorMessage.sharedIntance.show(title: "このクーポンは取得済です。", message: "")
                }else {
                    ErrorMessage.sharedIntance.show(title: "マイクーポンに追加されました", message: "")
                }

            case .failure(let error):
                debugPrint(error)
                ErrorMessage.sharedIntance.show(title: "マイクーポンに追加できませんでした", message: "")
                break
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: Is the variable `json` defined above the line `if json["returnCode"]...`? No, it's not. You forgot  to assign the JSON of the response to the variable `json`

Comment: Thanks.
So you mean like this `let json` `var json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Alamofire—Response Handling](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#response-handling):

```
if let json = response.result.value {
    print("JSON: \(json)") // serialized json response
}
```

In your case, `switch response.result … case .success(let data):` is an alternate way to get the data in `response.result.value`.

However, you named the variable `data` instead of `json`. If you change the name it should work.

```
Alamofire.request(APIURL.k_Coupon_Publish, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding(destination: .httpBody), headers: ApiService.sharedInstance.header)
    .validate(statusCode: 200..<500)
    .responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let json): // <-- use json instead data.
            print(response)
            print(response.result)

           // Cast json to a string/any dictionary.
           // Get the return code and cast it as a string.
           // Finally, compare the return code to "E70".
           if let dict = json as? [String: Any], let code = dict["returnCode"] as? String, code == "E70" {
                ErrorMessage.sharedIntance.show(title: "このクーポンは取得済です。", message: "")
            }else {
                ErrorMessage.sharedIntance.show(title: "マイクーポンに追加されました", message: "")
            }

        case .failure(let error):
            debugPrint(error)
            ErrorMessage.sharedIntance.show(title: "マイクーポンに追加できませんでした", message: "")
            break
        }
}
```

Comment: New error get .. `Type 'Any' has no subscript members`

Comment: Just now I'm changing code that another developer made..
So I think there is compiler error ....

Comment: @SHIGE yeah, `json["returnCode"]` has not worked like that in a long time.

Comment: @SHIGE I stepped outside the original question to show a way to get the compare to work.